# Facebook API: getting persistent user auth access token

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

In a small app, where I am the only user (admin of the App), I would like to set access token once, and then reuse it. Instead of asking myself every day to allow the app permission. 
How do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Get User Token Associated With App:

- on developers.facebook.com, click Tools then Graph API Explorer
  select your App from the application select box on top right click
  "Get Token" button, then "Get user access token" select the
  permissions necessary for you, and submit, then allow this access in
  the upcoming popup window copy the received User Access Token

2) get long life user token (~60 days?)

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app id}&client_secret={app secret}&fb_exchange_token={user access token from previous step}

response:

access_token={new user access token}&expires={...}